# How can I run pycausalimpact to determine and measure causation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, causality

I came across pycausalimpact recently.

https://pypi.org/project/pycausalimpact/

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import ArmaProcess
from causalimpact import CausalImpact


np.random.seed(12345)
ar = np.r_[1, 0.9]
ma = np.array([1])
arma_process = ArmaProcess(ar, ma)
X = 100 + arma_process.generate_sample(nsample=100)
y = 1.2 * X + np.random.normal(size=100)
y[70:] += 5

data = pd.DataFrame({'y': y, 'X': X}, columns=['y', 'X'])
pre_period = [0, 69]
post_period = [70, 99]

ci = CausalImpact(data, pre_period, post_period)
print(ci.summary())
print(ci.summary(output='report'))
ci.plot()
```

That generic code works fine in the given example.  Now, I am trying to run my own data in that pycausalimpact example, as shown below.

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
import statsmodels as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.structural import UnobservedComponents
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import ArmaProcess
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from causalimpact import CausalImpact
import warnings

y = fus['days']
X = fus[['market_cat',
               'mmepool_cat',
               'submarket_cat',
               'local_market_cat',
               'project_type_cat',
               'site_status_cat',
               'city_cat',
               'state_cat']]
```

The part that I am struggling with is here:

```
ci = CausalImpact(data, pre_period, post_period)
print(ci.summary())
print(ci.summary(output='report'))
ci.plot()
```

How do I need to prepare the 'data', the 'pre_period', and the 'post_period', to work in my specific data set?  Here is some of my actual data.

y =

[image]

X =

[image]

Basically, I want to see if there is any kind of causation effect between the independent variables and the dependent variable (days).  Or...is there a better/alternative way to determine and measure causation?